# Python pandas how to put a label in a new column depending on the set step?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with something like this column

| Comulative | Score |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 |
| -3 | 2 |
| -4 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| -1 | 1 |
| -4 | 2 |
| -8 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |

I would like to add a new filtering column in which if I specified two then it would mark all twos with ones according to the Score column

| Comulative | Score | Step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 1 | 0 |
| -3 | 2 | 1 |
| -4 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| -1 | 1 | 0 |
| -4 | 2 | 1 |
| -8 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 10 | 4 | 0 |

In my original csv file, the Comulative column usually does not change the sign from about 100 to 500 lines here , for clarity , it changes so often !

Can you tell me how to do it better ?

Comment: This is extremely unclear

Comment: I corrected it, but I'll try to explain it easier here. If I specify 5, then in the Step column, each five from the Score column is marked with one, if 8, then each 8 from the Score column and so on

Comment: So you want something like `df['step'] = df['Score'] == 2`

Comment: Yes, you are right and I have already figured out how to do it in general. Thank you very much! I'm sorry that I didn't express myself clearly at first, I'm 14 and I just recently started learning programming and I just sit experimenting and doing what comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So each time the sign changes in the `Comulative` column, the Score is reset to 1, then keeps increasing as long as the sign remain the same, right?

You need to create a temporary column to group contiguous rows that have the same sign.

```
df["temp"] = df["Comulative"]>0).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

At this point, you dataframe looks like this

```
>>> df
    Comulative  temp
0           -1     1
1           -3     1
2           -4     1
3            1     2
4            2     2
5            5     2
6           -1     3
7           -4     3
8           -8     3
9            1     4
10           3     4
11           5     4
12          10     4
```

Then you can compute your `Score` column with [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Computing `Step` is then pretty straightforward, and you just need to drop the `temp` column.

```
df["Score"] = df.groupby("temp", as_index=False).cumcount() + 1
df["Step"] = (df["Score"] == 2).astype(int)
df.drop(columns="temp", inplace = True)
```

And TADAA

```
>>> df
    Comulative  Score  Step
0           -1      1     0
1           -3      2     1
2           -4      3     0
3            1      1     0
4            2      2     1
5            5      3     0
6           -1      1     0
7           -4      2     1
8           -8      3     0
9            1      1     0
10           3      2     1
11           5      3     0
12          10      4     0
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you also tell me if it is possible for the units in the step column to observe the sign of the Comulative column!? That is, if Cumulative is negative, then the unit in step will be negative.

Comment: In general, I decided in my own way by converting the checks to true falls and just tried to change it with another check via .iloc. But your solution is clearly better so I'm going to change my code now

Comment: Something like this I tried to do:

df.loc[(df.Score == S1 and df.Comulative > 0), 'step'] = 2
df.loc[(df.Score == S1 and df.Comulative < 0), 'step'] = -2